# How to open .sqlitedb file in Visual Studio / Xamarin project?

Tags: c#, android-sqlite

I am working on a project that uses a .sqlitedb format to show a map in offline mode on a android phone. My filetype does not correlate to similar questions on SO and I can not open the file with how it is currently written that is the same as people that have the same problem but with the filetype .s3db, what am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SQLite;
using SQLitePCL;
using System.Data;


using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Graphics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MapplicationIII
{


public class TilesProvider : DataModel
{
    public SQLiteConnection db_con;
    public void Prepare() { }
    public sqlite3_stmt stmt;

public TilesProvider(String dbPath)
        {

            db_con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = [file path]\MapDataBase.sqlitedb;");

            //DataTable tables = db_con.GetTableInfo<db_con.GetTableInfo(string tiles_tb);

        }
}
}
```

I get the error:

SQLite.SQLiteException: Could not open database file

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the sample project of Xamarin named "Tasky"

To create the database:

```
    public SqliteConnection connection;
    public string path;
    static object locker = new object ();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Tasky.DL.TaskDatabase"/> TaskDatabase. 
    /// if the database doesn't exist, it will create the database and all the tables.
    /// </summary>
    public TaskDatabase (string dbPath) 
    {
        var output = "";
        path = dbPath;
        // create the tables
        bool exists = File.Exists (dbPath);

        if (!exists) {
            connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + dbPath);

            connection.Open ();
            var commands = new[] {
                "CREATE TABLE [Items] (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, Name NTEXT, Notes NTEXT, Done INTEGER);"
            };
            foreach (var command in commands) {
                using (var c = connection.CreateCommand ()) {
                    c.CommandText = command;
                    var i = c.ExecuteNonQuery ();
                }
            }
        } else {
            // already exists, do nothing. 
        }
        Console.WriteLine (output);
    }
```

To get items:

```
    public IEnumerable<Task> GetItems ()
    {
        var tl = new List<Task> ();

        lock (locker) {
            connection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=" + path);
            connection.Open ();
            using (var contents = connection.CreateCommand ()) {
                contents.CommandText = "SELECT [_id], [Name], [Notes], [Done] from [Items]";
                var r = contents.ExecuteReader ();
                while (r.Read ()) {
                    tl.Add (FromReader(r));
                }
            }
            connection.Close ();
        }
        return tl;
    }
```

with this examples it should be easy to implement it into your application in the same way

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the project?

Comment: I already have a database though. What I need is code to be able to open the .sqlitedb fileformat in this case?

Comment: @E.A.O.S then you only need the code at the bottom. You can't copy and paste it tho. You need to know the structure of your database and create a command-text that selects you all important information. If you send me the database I can help you

Comment: But I have those parts to, just the error is my problem of the filepath not being accepted, but I can send the database to you, where do I send it to?